# jquery pass variable to dynamic onclick

Tags: jquery

I want to pass this variable ( location of a list item) after I dynamically created a button

location of list that I want to pass to button and creation

```
var selected = $(this).closest('li');

selected.append('<button class="topcoat-button">Back</button>');
```

current code to capture button clicked from dynamic button creation

```
$(document).on('click', '.topcoat-button', function() {
    alert("clicked button");
});
```

Comment: So... what's the "location of list"?

Comment: Why do you need to pass it? Can you not set the variable within the click handler?

Comment: By "location of list" are you referring to the `li` that is set in `var selected`?

Comment: Pass what from what, the question is not very clear?

Comment: I have the location an item in a list.  I want to pass that to the button so I can reset some things in that list item

Comment: but what is this "location", where are you getting it from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript functions can reference variables in the scope of their enclosing functions.

That is to say, if you have code like this:

```
var location = 3

$(document).on('click', '.topcoat-button', function() {
    alert(location);
});
```

Clicking the button will alert the value `3` as the child function was defined with the scope in which the variable was declared.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brandonhorst/sYJYL/). Play around with it and see if this fulfills your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can just get grab the parent in the `.on` function...

```
$(document).on('click', '.topcoat-button', function() {
  var $li = $(this).parent("li");
  alert("clicked button");
});
```